# Can I initialize static values at booting code in google test?

Tags: c++, googletest

I am making a template class which is a interface of id generator class.
I can compile and run the code with google test. And I could confirm staticInitializer() in the following code initializes variable generator_ as non-null value. However, it will be null value in the google test. 
Although I can initialize it in SetUp() function and it works well, I would not like to to modify my code only for google test if possible.

How to initialize static variable which is initialized once at the booting code with google test?

```
#include <memory>

template<typename Generator>
class IdGenerator {
public:
    using GeneratorType = Generator;
    using ShareGeneratorType = std::shared_ptr<GeneratorType>;

    IdGenerator() {
        staticInitializer();
    };

    static void staticInitializer(void) {
        // This function runs at booting code once. At the time,
        // the following generator_ is non-null value, but it will
        // be null value in google test.
        ShareGeneratorType new_generator = ShareGeneratorType(new Generator());
        generator_ = new_generator;
    }

    template <typename ObjectType>
    static int nextId(void) {
        return generator_->nextId<ObjectType>();
    }

private:
    static ShareGeneratorType generator_;

};

class IdGeneratorImpl {
public:
    template <typename ObjectType>
    int nextId(void) {
        // ObjectSelector<ObjectType> is a traits class which gives index of ObjectType
        static auto object_index = ObjectSelector<ObjectType>::index;
        return ++id_counters_[object_index];
    }
private:
    static constexpr int no_of_types_ = 4;
    std::array<int, no_of_types_> id_counters_;
};
```

The IdGenerator runs and initializes its static member, generator_, from  static_initialization.hpp file.

```
//static_initialization.hpp
IdGenerator<IdGeneratorImpl> for_static_initializatoin;
```

Comment: Why do you need to share the same generator among every instance of your class?

Comment: @Rerito : Thank you for commenting. I want id generator to be a singleton to keep consistency. I am making experimental codes to learn c++. And I stick to a problem I encountered to learn c++ and tools around it. So my decision may not be best or not be reasonable.